# How to remove the child element(s) in a text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea to explore this. I am appending the `span` element on select of a text in the div. works fine.

In case if the user select again the `span` element(text inside or out side) how to remove the existing element and wrap in to new `span` element. so i will not get a children for any `span` element. (span is the parent, children allowed other than span element)

How to clear the `span` in the text selection?

I am applying border to spans(hightlight)

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wx9b1r/3/)

js:

```
function selHTML() {
    var nNd = document.createElement("span");
    var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);   

    console.log(w); 
    try {
            w.surroundContents(nNd);
            $(nNd).addClass('highlight');
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.")
        }

}

$("#addText").on('click',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selHTML());
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $(selHTML());
});

$("div.content").mouseup(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (!range.collapsed) {
        var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = bounds.left + ((bounds.right - bounds.left - $(".savetooltipAll").outerWidth()) / 2);
        var y = bounds.top - $(".savetooltipAll").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".savetooltipAll").css("top", (y+(bounds.top*3)) + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").css("left",x + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").show();

    } else {
        $(".savetooltipAll").hide();
    }
});

$("div.content").mousedown(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection();
    console.log(range.type);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the selection has highlighted span and if exist remove the span in range before highlighting. See below condition,

```
    if (w.startContainer.parentElement.className == 'highlight') {
        $(w.startContainer.parentElement).replaceWith(function () {
            return $(this).contents();
        });
    }
```

**Note:** The above is just a concept you can use. The code looks for `span.highlight`, you can expand the check if you decide to unwrap other elements too.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jsr150L5/

```js
function selHTML() {
    var nNd = document.createElement("span");
    var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

    console.log(w);
    console.log(w.startOffset + ' ' + w.endOffset);
    try {
        if (w.startContainer.parentElement.className == 'highlight') {
            $(w.startContainer.parentElement).replaceWith(function () {
                return $(this).contents();
            });
        }
        if (w.endContainer.parentElement.className == 'highlight') {
            $(w.endContainer.parentElement).replaceWith(function () {
                return $(this).contents();
            });
        }
        w.surroundContents(nNd);
        $(nNd).addClass('highlight');
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.")
    }

}

$("#addText").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selHTML());
});

$("button").click(function () {
    $(selHTML());
});

$("div.content").mouseup(function (event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (!range.collapsed) {
        var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = bounds.left + ((bounds.right - bounds.left - $(".savetooltipAll").outerWidth()) / 2);
        var y = bounds.top - $(".savetooltipAll").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".savetooltipAll").css("top", (y + (bounds.top * 3)) + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").css("left", x + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").show();

    } else {
        $(".savetooltipAll").hide();
    }
});

$("div.content").mousedown(function (event) {
    var range = window.getSelection();
    console.log(range.type);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.savetooltipAll {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong>&nbsp;adipisicing elit. Error ipsa quo illum excepturi autem voluptatem, maiores tempora quasi temporibus architecto ratione delectus modi qui cum earum, omnis itaque nam iure!</p>
</div>
<div class="savetooltipAll">
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
<input type="button" id="addText" value="Surround">
```

Comment: You are correct. but i am getting an error as `The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.` while mixing the `strong` on select with other text

Comment: @3gwebtrain The condition `w.startContainer.parentElement.className == 'highlight'` checks only for `span.highlight` in the selection. Change the condition if you want to include the `<strong>` tag in there.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that every time the user makes a selection you simply clear ALL the spans out of the parent element. Then you can start fresh each time, allowing you to implement the logic to keep track of where these spans are going.

In addition, every time you create a span, you should store the data of the starting index and ending index in the text. This way, you don't rely on the span elements telling you where those selections are, and your logic can be decoupled from creation of the view or display.

You can store multiple sets of start and end points as well, so that as the user selects multiple areas, one after the other, they continually get added to your data. You might end up with something like this:

```
[
    {start: 2, end: 6},
    {start: 8, end: 21}
]
```

*(an array, where each object inside represents a single selection, or "span")*

Now that you have this data, you can check the objects for overlaps.. if one ends after another begins, just merge them together into one.

After all your logic is complete, you can re-add your span elements into the page.